# How to get around NAT on mobile phones while using 3G?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, symbian3

I am wondering how can I make real time data exchanges on mobile phones like whatapps, viber or skype do on phones. Until now I managed to make a server work on my android phone with web services but it works only with a wifi network as when we use 3G or edge connections, we have private IP Addresses and I can't be joined when using 3G. Of course I can buy a public IP address but I didn't have to when I use viber or whatapps, so I guess there is a solution.
So my question is how to get around those NAT (Network Address Translation) without having to make a periodic check for data?

Answer (score 0):

A bit vague question. But these apps all basically do either tunneling via external server or [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). And there are [lots of different techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal#See_also) available...

Comment: i know they pass by  external servers but still users get their messages in real time. I mean without making a periodic backrgound check as it consumes

Comment: @youssoua See NAT traversal ^^

Comment: thx, i've seen some interest hints there.. going to look deeper to find a solution..
Greetings :-)

Answer (score -1):

Since phones can change their IP interface (and address) every few seconds, defeating NAT may not be such a good idea.

Comment: do u have any other idea?? i know but for now that's the only way i have to retrieve data (works only with wifi)